# How to remove address and shipping checkouts in prestashop 1.7.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I have been able to remove the two procedures successfully, the detail is that when I try to finish, it recharges the payment part and only the user registers me. Just remove a few lines from the ordercontroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEMDM.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, do you want to remove the Address, Shipping Method and Payment step from checkout?

Unfortunately, deleting a few lines from the OrderController is not enough.
The shipping/invoice address is required to place an order, there is no really a way to delete it.

You can delete/disable the Payment step if your product is free, and also you can disable the Shipping method step if your product is a "Virtual Product".

Maybe a workaround for the Address step, if create and address which you assign to each client right after the registration (but this is not the right solution because of the GDPR ).

Comment: my solution was to fill in those fields and hide the forms, just to be able to continue in step two and three, and when I reach the fourth the purchase is finalized, the fields of the give an id and fill them by javascript

Comment: Hello @RicardoRivera have you found a solution?
thank you